# Exadata: how to backup system before upgrade rpm packages?

Tags: backup, exadata

My PCI scanned found some vulnerabilities on my Exadata. I must upgrade glibc package.

Before that I want to backup the system not to ruin something. By which tool can I backup OS?

I used acronis, clonezilla but maybe I have old version , because they are not able to backup the system.

Please, give me any advice.

Comment: Ask Oracle support. I really wouldn't do anything like that without their blessing, especially glibc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is the following:
Create LVM Snapshot-Based Backup for your OS.
Refer below link in steps to perform the same. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50790_01/doc/doc.121/e51951/db_server.htm#DBMMN22020 
2 Maintaining Database Servers of Oracle Exadata Database Machine 
Section: 
Creating a Snapshot-Based Backup of Oracle Linux Database Server